# Set of runnable is not working correctly - handler

Tags: java, android, runnable, android-handler

I'm doing an application in which I have to show a sequence of pictures: The sequence is the follow:

1. A red X has to be shown for more or less 1000 milliseconds;
2. An image called "Screenshot" has to be shown for more or less 50
   milliseconds;
3. An image called "Noise" has to be shown for more or less 50
   milliseconds;
4. The "Noise" image disappear to make space for an EditText.

The `EditText` is used to get the user data.

My idea to do that is using a set of runnable. Here is the code:

```
private void startThread0(){
    handler.postDelayed(new TaskCross(), 1000);
    handler.postDelayed(new TaskScreenshot(0), 2000);
    handler.postDelayed(new TaskNoise(), 2100);
    handler.postDelayed(new TaskEditText(), 3000);

    myEditText.setOnKeyListener(null);

    myEditText.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener(){
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            System.out.println("KEY ENTER!!!!!");
            if((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {
                if(myEditText.getText().toString().equals("")){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Inserire un numero da 1 a 9", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return false;
                } else if (Integer.parseInt(myEditText.getText().toString()) >= 1 &&
                        Integer.parseInt(myEditText.getText().toString()) <= 9){
                    startThread1(1);
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }       
    });
}

private void startThread1(final int i){     

    if(i < length){
        handler.postDelayed(new TaskCross(), 1000);
        handler.postDelayed(new TaskScreenshot(i), 2000);
        handler.postDelayed(new TaskNoise(), 2100);
        handler.postDelayed(new TaskEditText(), 3000);

        myEditText.setOnKeyListener(null);

        myEditText.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener(){
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                System.out.println("KEY ENTER!!!!!");
                if((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {
                    if(myEditText.getText().toString().equals("")){
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Inserire un numero da 1 a 9", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        return false;
                    } else if (Integer.parseInt(myEditText.getText().toString()) >= 1 &&
                            Integer.parseInt(myEditText.getText().toString()) <= 9){
                        startThread1(i+1);
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }       
        });

        if(i == length-1 && myEditText.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE){            
            continueButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
int[] screenshots = {
           R.drawable.googleplaybooks2,
           R.drawable.aldiko1,
           R.drawable.chaton2,
           R.drawable.cinetrailer1,
           R.drawable.fanpage1
    };
```

---

```
class TaskScreenshot implements Runnable{

        int j;

        public TaskScreenshot(int _i){
            this.j = _i;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Screenshot --> " + j);
            myEditText.setText("");
            myEditText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            myImageFragment.getView().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            myImageView.setImageResource(screenshots[j]);
            myImageView.getLayoutParams().width = LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
            myImageView.getLayoutParams().height = LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
        }
    }

    class TaskNoise implements Runnable{

        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Noise");
            myImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.noise);
            myImageView.getLayoutParams().width = LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
            myImageView.getLayoutParams().height = LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
        }
    }

    class TaskEditText implements Runnable{

        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("EditText");
            myEditText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            myImageFragment.getView().setVisibility(View.GONE);
            myEditText.requestFocus();
        }
    }

    class TaskCross implements Runnable{

        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Cross");
            myEditText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            myImageFragment.getView().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            myImageView.getLayoutParams().width = 90;
            myImageView.getLayoutParams().height = 90;
            myImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.cross300x300);
        }
    }
```

Now, when I try to execute the threads, this is the result on the logcat:

```
Cross
Screenshot --> 0
Noise
EditText

Cross
Cross
Screenshot --> 1
Screenshot --> 2
Noise
Noise
EditText
EditText

Cross
Cross
Screenshot --> 3
Screenshot --> 4
Noise
Noise
EditText
EditText
```

Thus, the first screeshot is right and, after that, the other screenshots are shown two at a time. Why? Is there something wrong with the timer of the `Handler`? 
Thanks!

Comment: You've posted a lot a code here. You'll have more luck if you narrow it down to where you're having the issue.

Comment: I know it is a lot of code, but I think the problem is somewhere in the code I've posted.

Comment: I would suggest you first refactor, then. You have a ton of duplication which makes it a little difficult to reason about what's going on. You want to minimize the amount of work a person has to do in order to help you. Remove the duplication and use meaningful variable names (not `i`, `j`, `y`, etc) and my guess is that you'll then be able to spot the problem yourself.

Comment: It's best to use the AsyncTask class when dealing with threads on Android. I'm not completely sure what you're trying to do here but an AsycTask would most likely take care of it much more easily.

Comment: I've added more information. Anyway, the purpose of this code is to display synchronized thread (e.g. thread1 -> thread2 -> thread3 ...) one at a time and not in background, so I don't think `AsyncTask` is the proper solution of my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your Runnables are executing on what appears to be the main thread handler, not a thread pool. A Runnable is simply an interface for delegating the execution of a task.

Now, I'd strongly recommend using a AnimationDrawable for most of this instead of trying to reinvent the wheel.

```
<animation-list android:oneshot="true">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/cross300x300" android:duration="1000" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/googleplaybooks2" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/aldiko1" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/chaton2" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/cinetrailer1" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/fanpage1" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/noise" android:duration="50" />
</animation-list>
```

You haven't posted how the rest of your Views and Layouts are set up, so it's a little difficult to say the best way for you to integrate this with your code. But however you do it, you can use AnimationDrawable.start() to begin the animation. For transitioning to your EditText, you could use AnimationDrawable.getDuration() to send a delayed message or Runnable to your handler. Or you could make use of subclassing.

Hopefully this will get you started down a better (less complicated) path for your code.

Comment: the sequence should be like this: cross -> googleplaybooks2 -> noise -> edittext; this sequence is repeated for every screenshot in the array.